# QDesktopServices::openUrl and gvfs-open issue

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu

I'm trying to open a local file using QDesktopServices::openUrl under ubuntu, it appears to use gvfs-open .If the file name is correct, then the PDF pops up . 
If the file name is wrong, of course gvfs-open does not manage to open the file.However,the return value of the function is true. That is, the function does not detect that the PDF failed to open the file. 
What should I do to get the correct result of opening?
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: what Qt version are you using?

Comment: QtSDK-linux-x86-v1.0.2 ,qt 4.8.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect if file exists with [QFile::exists](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfile.html#exists) 
before calling `openUrl()`